# Where can I ask questions about integration with Oracle products?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which SE site, if any, would be the right place to ask questions about Oracle products, particularly about integration with Opera?

It's neither code nor DB related, so it won't be welcome in StackOverflow/DBA. It's about which API to choose for a given task.

Is there a SE site for this topic? Or if someone can recommend a non-SE site, that'd be welcome too. Oracle's community forums have no activity.

Comment: Such recommendations tend to OT, but [here's general guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/889718/3648282), offered before it was closed, that might help you; possibly to help you refine your question, or steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to sit down and have a conversation with a consultant, going through your requirements and coming up with a solution.

That's not a Q&A post.

It *may* be acceptable on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) but nobody really knows what's on topic there so don't quote me on that.

And there are always chat rooms...

Comment: *nobody really knows what's on topic there* ... you have had a bad experience?

Comment: Yeah, Software Engineering is a bit wiggly regarding scope :)

Comment: @rene I only notice that all kinds of not so well researched question are landing there.

Comment: @rene Not personally but I think this is a well-known fact :)